# R: dplyr filter timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, dplyr

I have the following data frame wrapped by `tbl_df`. Note that the 2nd column `timestamp` was formatted as `timestamp=format(df[,2], format="%H:%M:%OS")` follow before being wrapped by `tbl_df`.

```
> out$ts_tbl
# A tibble: 1,903 × 3
         date    timestamp value
       <dttm>       <fctr> <int>
1  2016-07-04 09:15:00.099 8
2  2016-07-04 09:15:00.099 2
3  2016-07-04 09:15:00.099 9
4  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 1
5  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 2
6  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 3
7  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 5
8  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 10
9  2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 10
10 2016-07-04 09:15:00.152 1
# ... with 1,903 more rows
```

Somehow after wrapping the data frame by `tbl_df`, the timestamp columns become factors.

**My goal is to be able to filter the timestamp** before "09:16:00.000" (or **filter timestamp within a certain range**). I tried:

```
> output$ts_tbl %>% filter(timestamp < "09:16:00.000")
```

Then I have the following output which complains that the timestamps are factors under `tbl_df` (shown below).  Can someone kindly help me out here please?

```
# A tibble: 0 × 3
# ... with 3 variables: date <dttm>, timestamp <fctr>, value <int>
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(c(14L, 14L, 14L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L,  :
  ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: But the 2nd column only contains the time with no dates. How can I convert that?

Comment: I posted a solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert it to `times` class with `chron` and do the `filter`

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(times(timestamp)< times("09:16:00"))
# A tibble: 7 × 3
#        date    timestamp value
#       <chr>       <fctr> <int>
#1 2016-07-04 09:15:00.099     8
#2 2016-07-04 09:15:00.099     2
#3 2016-07-04 09:15:00.099     9
#4 2016-07-04 09:15:00.152     1
#5 2016-07-04 09:15:00.152     2
#6 2016-07-04 09:15:00.152     3
#7 2016-07-04 09:15:00.152     5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", 
"2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-04", 
"2016-07-04", "2016-07-04"), timestamp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("09:15:00.099", "09:15:00.152", 
"09:16:00.152", "09:17:00.152"), class = "factor"), value = c(8L, 
2L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", "timestamp", 
"value"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
 "9", "10"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```